# Integrating Geolocation Libraries and Handling CSV Data in a Node.js Web Application

Tags: javascript, node.js

As part of a project, we are retrieving a list of coordinates between two geographical points. We would like, from this large table of coordinates, to obtain for each of them the nearest unique city. For this, we have a .csv file containing all the municipalities in France with their respective coordinates. Locally, we have a function that does exactly what we just described, and it works well. The idea is to visualize the results on a web application.

The problem arises when we deploy our NodeJs project (localhost:3000) => we receive errors of the type "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined." Indeed, these libraries are not accessible on the front end. We found one that could help us in our project, namely Geolib (https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib). However, we can't use it, whether locally or by inserting the script tag in the index.html file.

How do we use libraries once the code is deployed? How can I read the data from my csv file locally, in my browser? Should I host this file somewhere other than locally? Our project is in NodeJs with an Express server.

Thank you!

I tried to add the librairy `const geolib = require('geolib');`
, using import { getDistance } from 'geolib';
, and added the 
tag in my html files. Neither of them were working.